# Paypal account for a second shop so that the payment always appears in the name of the store the client is shopping in

Tags: ecommerce, multiple-domains, paypal

I have one online store, let's say, AAA store with a PayPal gateway. Now i want to open another store, BBB store, with the same account (if possible, but it's not my main concern). Of course, for the customers, the charge has to appear on their statement as "BBB store".

I read a lot about secondary account, child account, but at the end this is very confusing and i didn't found any "how to" for open any of those so-called secondary accounts. I just know that a second business account is against PayPal policies.

Furthermore, I specify that both stores are managed by the same company, and same manager (account owner). I can provide a different store name, different emails, even different bank account (but same owner).

At the end, I just want two stores where customers are charged under the store's name.

Comment: Have you contacted PayPal tech support?  They would have the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like several multi-domains users, I also suffered the same **limitation of only one PayPal business account per company**.

As it depends on PayPal's rules there is no true solution so far.

**A pragmatic way of dealing with this limitation is to indicate to whom the stores belong**:

- on the pages of store AAA, write: "AAA is a service of CCC" (the company)
- on the pages of store BBB, write: "BBB is a service of CCC"

"a division of" / "operated by", a.s.o., you can choose the best formula that applies to your stores.

**This way, your users won't be too disoriented during the payment process.**

If one of your stores becomes big enough, you could then create a new company, that acquire it, and consequently open a a second PayPal business account.